# Como puedo inhabilitar seleccionar los dias lunes a viernes en un input date?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo esta seccion de código y quisiera que no se puedan seleccionar los días Lunes a Viernes

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="wrap-input3">
      <h3 class="contact3-form-subtitle">Fecha de pedido:</h3>
      <div>
        <input type="date" id="fecha_pedido" name="fecha_pedido" required="1" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border: 5px solid #1db33b; width:100%" />
</div>
```

Estoy abierto a diferentes alternativas, gracias a todos!

Comment: ¿y que has intentado?

Comment: Si han respondido a tu pregunta valórala y vótala como respuesta, al tick de abajo

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la mejor manera sería hacer una validación del día por medio del evento `change`, pasas el evento y evaluas la expresión con los métodos relacionados a `Date`.

```js
function validar(e) {
  const dia = (new Date(e.target.value)).getDay();
  if (dia <= 4) { //Cualquier día menor que Viernes
    e.target.value = ""; //Resetear la fecha
    alert("Fecha inválida"); //Dar feedback al usuario
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="wrap-input3">
      <h3 class="contact3-form-subtitle">Fecha de pedido:</h3>
      <div>
        <input type="date" id="fecha_pedido" name="fecha_pedido" required="1" onchange="validar(event)" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr style="border: 5px solid #1db33b; width:100%" />
</div>
```